# Is it possible to make multiple copies of a file to HDFS in gradle

Tags: hadoop, gradle, hdfs

I am using gradle tasks to setup some tests. For this, I need to copy a file to HDFS location. While I am able to achieve this, is it possible to make multiple copies of the same file with renaming each file uniquely.

Comment: Does my answer solve the problem? If so, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you're looking for:

```
task copyRename << {
  ['a', 'b', ].each { n ->
    copy {
      from(project.rootDir) {
        include 'lol'
        rename { "lol-$n" }
      }
      into('dest')
    }
  }
}
```

?

Demo can be found [here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/34670831).